# Can't access some samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, file-sharing

I have an Ubuntu server (19.04) and 4 HDD with my datas on them.
I have 4 samba shares, 1 for each HDD, All the HDD are setup the same way.
When trying to access them from Windows, I can access 3 of them no problems, but HDD_4 doesn't want to work.

here is the smb.conf :

```
[HDD_1]
    path = /mnt/HDD_1
    create mode = 777
    directory mode = 777
    map hidden = yes
    writeable = yes

[HDD_2]
    path = /mnt/HDD_2
    create mode = 777
    directory mode = 777
    map hidden = yes
    writeable = yes

[HDD_3]
    path = /mnt/HDD_3
    create mode = 777
    directory mode = 777
    map hidden = yes
    writeable = yes

[HDD_4]
    path = /mnt/HDD_4
    create mode = 777
    directory mode = 777
    map hidden = yes
    writeable = yes
```

I used Webmin to setup my samba shares

I tried to search the logs and the only log I found with anything looking like it might help was this one.
/var/log/samba/Log.WindowsUsername :

```
[2019/06/05 21:00:05.935232,  0] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:412(change_to_user_internal)
  change_to_user_internal: chdir_current_service() failed!
```

All 4 HDD use the same samba user, tried a few different settings, but I don't know enough to do it with no fear :)
Here are a few I tried :
- set the user to my sambauser
- set guest access to yes
- set force unix user to my sambauser

still no love. As for the error in Windows it says cannot access, "you do not have the permission to access the share"

Please help :)

Comment: Run "ls -al /mnt". Do the permissions on HDD_4 match the other ones and more importantly does it allow access to the samba client?

Comment: When trying `ls -al /mnt`  I get this error message : `Error: unknown argument '-l'`

Comment: My bad, bad alias. So indeed not the same. `drwx------` vs `drwxrwsr-x+`. So I suppose I need to chmod my way through it ? Edit : All good now, Thanks ! :)